# How to change color of a word in text after WP update

Tags: options, design, color-picker

Since the latest WP update it changed my setting. Normally I had a ''change text color'' setting in the red area (see screenshot). Anyone can guide me how to add the option in this field?

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing any code in this question, this stack is for developers but this looks like a user support question that might be better on the wp.org support forums, not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in WordPress, you will need to consult the 3rd party plugins you have installed to identify the plugin that provided it then contact their support.

But you shouldn't need it, as WordPress already provides this feature, and it's visible in your screenshot as highlight:

[image]

Which brings up a colour picker:

[image]